# use throttle to limit number of wrong mod requests

Tags: python, django, request, throttling

i want to limit wrong method requests in my django app, for example i have GET method on one of my urls and other methods like post, put, patch, delete are not allowed for that url path and even not implemented.

i want to count number of requests for not allowed methods and don't allow user requests be more than 10 times for that not allowed methods. and at the same time i don't have any limitation constraint for get method on the same url.

Comment: If you already disallow the methods what more do you want to happen, other than returning a 405, after 10 attempts?

Comment: If you just want to limit the number of requests, you can try to use django-ratelimit `https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/`